# Is it possibile to have both InlineKeyboard and ReplyKeyboard on telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Is it possible to have both keyboards (telegram.InlineKeyboard and telegram.ReplyKeyboard) under a single message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, that's not possible. the `reply_markup` parameter of `send_message` & friends only accepts one keyboard. The closest you can get is to send two messages with one keyboard each and delete the message with the `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` right away.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly I need both of them. I'll think another way